# Access denied issue in getting Modern SharePoint site analytics with Graph API

Tags: api, sharepoint, graph, analytics

I am facing Access Denied. The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. issue in getting Modern SharePoint site analytics with Graph API. Whereas with classic SharePoint sites it is working fine. All Graph permissions are applied as mentioned in this document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/itemactivitystat-getactivitybyinterval?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

This seems to the problem with .Net Graph Client because with MS Graph Explorer I get activities for both classic and modern sites.

```
var itemAnalytics = await graphServiceClient1.Sites["{modern-site-id}"]
    .GetActivitiesByInterval("2018-01-01", "2020-09-03", "day")
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be your permission configuration problem.

This a demo on how to call Graph API in c#.

https://www.olivercoding.com/2019-01-01-azure-graph/

[image]